# Flutter - Add Layers on top of ListView to scroll

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I am making a reader app and I have a ListView.builder which is loading multiple Images from the API. Now I want to add a layer on top of the ListView with 2 transparent containers so that when I click the left container the list goes up and when I click the right container the list goes down. I tried adding the ListView to stack but then the scrolling ability of the list is gone. This is my code so far:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollViewController,
            cacheExtent: 1000,
            itemCount: _picLinkMap.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
              return buildImageLoader(
                  _picLinkMap[index], index + 1);
            },
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: mySize.width * 0.5,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  print("Tap Left");
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: mySize.width * 0.5,
                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  print("Tap RIGHT");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
    ),
);
```

I only want to scroll about half the height of the screen on tap.
I searched the web but did not find a suitable solution.

Comment: @pskink I don't want to show any buttons over the screen. The images are more specifically comics & hence the buttons will block the view. I only added the colors to the containers in the above code only for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollController _scrollViewController = ScrollController();

...

var jumpTo = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 104)/2; 
//104 is random number for the rest of the screen widgets (e.g. appbar ..)

_scrollViewController.jumpTo(jumpTo); //pixel value

...

ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollViewController,
```

Comment: No, I know that but the problem is with the layout. I am not able to add the row on top of listview as stated in my code above. Cause if I did that then the scroll of listview does not work.